# C# Discord.Net bot - how to post message once every X hours?

Tags: c#, discord.net

I'm writing a discord bot in C# with Discord.NET API.

I was wondering if I could get a few pointers on how to make my bot post a message in a channel every 6 hours.

Details required by stack overflow:

I have the commands set up. I followed a tutorial and found some code to get this far. I know I have to use a timer, but I'm not sure how to hook it into the discord .NET api.

Thank you.

Here's the code I have so far.

Program.cs
https://pastebin.com/rMjY8MAE

```
using Discord;
using Discord.Commands;
using Discord.WebSocket;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using SQLitePCL;
 
namespace PrayerBot
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args) => new Program().RunBot().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
 
        // Creating the necessary variables
        public static DiscordSocketClient _client;
        private CommandService _commands;
        private IServiceProvider _services;
 
        private BotConfig config;
 
        // Runbot task
        public async Task RunBot()
        {
            _client = new DiscordSocketClient(); // Define _client
            _commands = new CommandService(); // Define _commands
 
            _services = new ServiceCollection() // Define _services
                .AddSingleton(_client)
                .AddSingleton(_commands)
                .BuildServiceProvider();
 
            config = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BotConfig>(File.ReadAllText("config.json"));
 
            string botToken = config.token; // Make a string for the token
 
            _client.Log += Log; // Logging
 
            await RegisterCommandsAsync(); // Call registercommands
 
            await _client.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bot, botToken); // Log into the bot user
 
            await _client.StartAsync(); // Start the bot user
 
            await _client.SetGameAsync(config.game); // Set the game the bot is playing
 
            await Task.Delay(-1); // Delay for -1 to keep the console window opened
        }
 
        private async Task RegisterCommandsAsync()
        {
            _client.MessageReceived += HandleCommandAsync; // Messagerecieved
 
            await _commands.AddModulesAsync(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly(), null); // Add module to _commands
        }
 
        private Task Log(LogMessage arg) // Logging
        {
            Console.WriteLine(arg); // Print the log to Console
            return Task.CompletedTask; // Return with completedtask
        }
 
        private async Task HandleCommandAsync(SocketMessage arg)
        {
            string messageLower = arg.Content.ToLower(); // Convert the message to a Lower
            var message = arg as SocketUserMessage; // Create a variable with the message as SocketUserMessage
            if (message is null || message.Author.IsBot) return; // Checks if the message is empty or sent by a bot
            int argumentPos = 0; // Sets the argpos to 0 (the start of the message)
            if (message.HasStringPrefix(config.prefix, ref argumentPos) || message.HasMentionPrefix(_client.CurrentUser, ref argumentPos)) // If the message has the prefix at the start or starts with someone mentioning the bot
            {
                var context = new SocketCommandContext(_client, message); // Create a variable called context
                var result = await _commands.ExecuteAsync(context, argumentPos, _services); // Create a veriable called result
                if (!result.IsSuccess) // If the result is unsuccessful
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(result.ErrorReason); // Print the error to console
                    await message.Channel.SendMessageAsync(result.ErrorReason); // Print the error to the channel where the error was caused (e.g "Unknown Command")
                }
            }
        }
    }
 
    class BotConfig
    {
        public string token { get; set; }
        public string prefix { get; set; }
        public string game { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Commands.cs
https://pastebin.com/1EK3M1Fi

```
using Discord.Commands;
using Microsoft.Data.Sqlite;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
 
namespace PrayerBot
{
    public class Commands : ModuleBase<SocketCommandContext>
    {
        [Command("ping")]
        private async Task Ping()
        {
            await ReplyAsync("Pong!  **" + Program._client.Latency + "ms**");
        }
 
        [Command("help")]
        private async Task Help()
        {
            string returnStr = "Worley Byrd Help\n"; 
            returnStr += "~addprayer prayer - this adds a prayer\n";
            returnStr += "~viewprayers - view prayers that haven't been answered\n";
            returnStr += "~answerprayer id# - mark prayer# as answered\n";
 
            await ReplyAsync(returnStr);
        }
 
        void setKeyValue(string name, string value)
        {
            string keyQuery = $"select value from keys where name='{name}'";
            string strValue = "";
 
            using (var connection = new SqliteConnection("Data Source=prayers.s3db"))
            {
                connection.Open();
 
                var command = connection.CreateCommand();
                command.CommandText = keyQuery;
 
                using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        strValue = reader.GetString(0);
                    }
                }
            }
 
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(strValue))
            {
                //insert
                string insertQuery = $"insert into keys(name,value) values('{name}','{value}')";
 
 
                using (var connection = new SqliteConnection("Data Source=prayers.s3db"))
                {
                    connection.Open();
 
                    var cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
                    cmd.CommandText = insertQuery;
 
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //update
                string updateQuery = $"update keys set value='{value}' where name='{name}'";
 
                using (var connection = new SqliteConnection("Data Source=prayers.s3db"))
                {
                    connection.Open();
 
                    var cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
                    cmd.CommandText = updateQuery;
 
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }
 
        [Command("serverinfo")]
        public async Task Serverinfo()
        {
            await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync($"This Discord server's name is {Context.Guild}");
        }
 
        [Command("posttochannel")]
        [Summary("Which channel to post prayers to")]
        public Task SetPostToChannel([Remainder][Summary("Set to this channel")] string channel)
        {
            string serverName = $"{Context.Guild}";
 
            setKeyValue($"posttochannel.{serverName}", channel);
 
            return ReplyAsync("Post Channel set to " + channel);
        }
 
 
        [Command("addprayer")]
        [Summary("Add's a prayer to the prayer DB")]
        public Task AddPrayerAsync([Remainder][Summary("The prayer to add")] string prayer)
        {
            string insertPrayer = string.Format("insert into prayers(prayer) values('{0}')", prayer);
 
            using (var connection = new SqliteConnection("Data Source=prayers.s3db"))
            {
                connection.Open();
 
                var command = connection.CreateCommand();
                command.CommandText = insertPrayer;
 
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
 
            return ReplyAsync("Prayer added!"); 
        }
 
        [Command("viewprayers")]
        [Summary("Add's a prayer to the prayer DB")]
        public Task ListPrayersAsync()
        {
            string selectPrayers = string.Format("select * from prayers where answered=0");
 
            string resultString = ""; 
 
            using (var connection = new SqliteConnection("Data Source=prayers.s3db"))
            {
                connection.Open();
 
                var command = connection.CreateCommand();
                command.CommandText = selectPrayers;
 
                using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while(reader.Read())
                    {
                        var id = reader.GetString(0); 
                        var prayer = reader.GetString(1);
 
                        resultString += String.Format("Prayer {0}: {1}\n", id, prayer);
                    }
                }
            }
 
            return ReplyAsync(resultString);
        }
 
        [Command("answerprayer")]
        [Summary("Add's a prayer to the prayer DB")]
        public Task AnswerPrayerAsync([Remainder][Summary("This prayer has been answered")] string id)
        {
            string updatePrayer = string.Format("update prayers set answered=1 where id=" + id);
 
            using (var connection = new SqliteConnection("Data Source=prayers.s3db"))
            {
                connection.Open();
 
                var command = connection.CreateCommand();
                command.CommandText = updatePrayer;
 
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
 
            return ReplyAsync(String.Format("Prayer {0} has been answered\n",id));
        }
 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a simple timer in your code:

```
myTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(6 * 60 * 60 * 1000); //calculate six hours in milliseconds
myTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
myTimer.Start();

private static void OnTimedEvent(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    YourMethod();
}
```

Comment: This is a timer, yes. But this doesn't explain how to send a message with Discord.NET once the timer triggers.